# Remove a link from selector

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            newLocation = this.href;
            $('#monster').fadeOut('slow', newpage);
        });
        function newpage() {
            window.location = newLocation;
        }
```

I am using the following code for the fade out effect for page transitions, whenever we click on any link ("a"), I want to remove this effect for 1 link with id "#flip", how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jQuery's `:not` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/). Also, I have switched your `click` function to `on` event handler, which is a bit more flexible to work with than the shorthand `click`. Personal preference there.

**jQuery**

```
$('a:not("#flip")').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // newLocation = this.href;
  // $('#monster').fadeOut('slow', newpage);
  alert('Only link tags without the #flip id should show this');
});

var newpage = function() {
  window.location = newLocation;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a href='#'>This link will work</a>
<a href='#'>This link will work</a>
<a href='#' id='flip'>This link will <b>not</b> work</a>
```

[JS Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/mjYLB/)

Comment: I do not know whats wrong, but all the link tags are showing the alert even the #flip

Comment: Even in the JS Fiddle example?

Comment: JSFiddle worked anyways never mind I did a stupid mistake x.x, feel smacking my head on the wall. <a> tag was inside <div> tag and <div> was named #flip :| thanks for your help. Really appreciate it.